# Remove HTML element classname with PHP?

Tags: php

Is it possible to remove a classname from a HTML element with PHP?

I know i can do this with Javascript, but i'm looking to something with less code.

I got a $_GET forward in the URL:

```
$add_article_status = $_GET['add_article_status'];
```

If the value is "success" then i will show a success alert.

The div element have a classname to stay hidden:

```
<div class="alert alert-success hidden_element">Success!</div>
```

Question:
Is it possible with PHP to remoce the classname: "hidden_element"

Or else maby i shall install a php var in the class like:

```
if($_GET['add_article_status'] == "success"){
    $hidden_element = "";
}

<div class="alert alert-success <?php echo $hidden_element ?>">Success!</div>
```

Comment: you could use PHP logic to change how html is output but really I think it is not PHP job to do.

Comment: Use ternary and generate it as it should be. `$add_article_status = !empty($_GET['add_article_status']) ? '' : ' hidden_element';`

Comment: <div class="alert alert-success".<?php !empty($_GET['add_article_status']) ? '' : ' hidden_element';?> >Success!</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to remove a classname from a HTML element with PHP?

You can and your code will work. But I have to make this clear, when you are inside PHP code, *do what you want*, everything happens before user saw the page. So if you are asking for **'How can I hide this element after couple of seconds user see?'**, you can't do that with PHP. But in that situation, you can mark that element with PHP for hiding later with JS or CSS.

In other situation, if you asking for **'How can I hide this element from beginning?'** you can either go with your code or use below code:

```
<?php
    $d = ($_GET['add_article_status'] == "success") ? "style='display:none'" : " ";
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success' $d>Success!</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
    $add_article_status = $_GET['add_article_status'];

if ($add_article_status == "success") {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Success!</div>";
}
```

Edit: Code has been corrected.

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

you can try in this way

```
//defaul hide all alert by passing the class
$show_alert_class = "hidden_element";
if($_GET['add_article_status'] == "success"){
    //if get the success show the alert
    $show_alert_class = "";
}

<div class="alert alert-success <?php echo $show_alert_class ?>">Success!</div>
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.